# Jquery Ajax not receiving php response correctly

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, json

I'm sending a JSON response from php to jquery:

```
foreach ( $obj as $o )
{ 
 $a[ $o->key] = utf8_encode($o->id);
}    
die(json_encode($a));
```

my html/jquery code is:

```
$.ajax({
  type:'POST',
  url: "imoveis/carrega_bairros",
  data: ({cidade:10}),  
  dataType:"json",                        
  success: function(ret)
  { alert(ret)      
    if(ret.success)
    {   
      // ...
    }
    else
     alert("error");
  }
});
```

The json response is perfect (i get it on the console), but jquery is receiving a NULL ret object and it alerts "error". What's the problem???

Comment: Have you examined the request / response using the console in your developer tools?

Comment: Yes, the response is a json encoded array like:
{"betel":"260","bom-retiro":"261","cascata":"262","centro":"263","chacara-de-recreio-barao":"264"}

Comment: @Theo Just out of curiosity, is there a reason you are returning the data in the `die()` function. Normally I've seen PHP `echo` the results back to the Ajax call as die is usual used in cases of errors. Either way it should work.

Comment: just testing, print doesn't work neither

Comment: Do you have `success` field defined in the JSON? Seems not.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add a JSON header to the top of your PHP file:

```
header('Content-type: application/json');
```

Comment: Nothing happens =/
I get a "[Object Object]" by using: alert(ret), but i cant do nothing with it!!!
ret.length returns undefined

Comment: @Theo `.length` is not a property of an object. You cannot do `object.length` as ultimately it will return undefined.

Comment: try replacing `alert(ret)` with `console.log(ret)`

Answer (score 1):

use this:-

```
<?php
$temp = array();
foreach ( $obj as $o )
{ 
 $temp[ $o->key] = utf8_encode($o->id);
 $a[] = $temp;
}    
die(json_encode(array('valid' => true,'content'=>$a)));
?>
```

in javascript:-

```
$.ajax({
    type:'POST',
    url: "imoveis/carrega_bairros",
    data: ({cidade:10}),  
    dataType:"json",                        
    success: function(ret)
    { 
        if(ret.valid == true)
        {
            // get your array as
            var arr = ret.content;
            alert(arr)
        }
        else
        {
            alert('error occured');
        }
    }
});
```